# sort a string slice: letters in alphabetical order *after* descending numbers

Tags: string, sorting, go, slice

given:

```
alphanumeric := ["aaa","bbb","ccc","111","222","333"]
```

after sorting:

```
["333","222","111","aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

tried for builtin sort package:

```
sort.Strings(alphanumeric)
```

it was close but numeric part will be ordered in ascending

["111","222","333","aaa","bbb","ccc"]

also:

```
sort.Slice(alphanumeric, func(i, j int) bool {
    return alphanumeric[i] > alphanumeric[j]
})
```

result was unwanted: ["ccc","bbb","aaa","333","222","111"]

pretty new to all the stuff, thank you for any hints

Comment: Show what you tried to solve this.

Comment: @BurakSerdar sorry updated.

Comment: Do not put "[SOLVED]" in your question title; SO has a mechanism for this, accepted answers. If you've solved it yourself, you can post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/hS4bo1q2tQl

```
sort.Slice(alphanumeric, func(i, j int) bool {
    // check if we have numbers, sort them accordingly 
    if z, err := strconv.Atoi(alphanumeric[i]); err == nil {
        if y, err := strconv.Atoi(alphanumeric[j]); err == nil {
        return y < z
    }
    // if we get only one number, alway say its greater than letter 
    return true
    }
    // compare letters normally 
    return alphanumeric[j] > alphanumeric[i]
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot! btw i found this could be failed if numbers are represented in decimal(1.236/ 2.0 etc.) or stand for some version numbers(1.0.0.2).
updated the post for a little mod.